# Programming for Android under Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Java Eclipse IDE for programming Android application. Recently Google changed requirements for publishing new apk's: it must have targetSdkVersion>=31.
I tried to sign apk inside Eclipse with targetSdkVersion=31 - but now Android says .apk format is corrupted.

I undestand that this way of programming for Android is obsolete, but I really don't like Android Studio.

My question is for guys who may still programming for Android under Eclipse: is there are a way to sign .APK inside Eclipse with targetSdkVersion>31?

Thanks.